# TCP Sampler in Jmeter Socket connection error

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, jmeter

I'm trying to send a message from Jmeter to a server via a TCP sampler
I have configured the IP, port number, and message in sent to message box then I started to hit server at this time I'm getting the following warning in Jmeter.

And also let me know the `TCP Client Class Name`, `End Of Line Byte` field value in Jmeter.

```
015/04/17 18:00:30 WARN  - **![jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler: Could not create socket for tcp://port&IP java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect][1]**
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.getSocket(TCPSampler.java:183)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.sample(TCPSampler.java:399)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

**socket connection error** in jmeter for tcp sampler configuration is resolved this exception  will raised when your server is not ready to take your request.
so before sending message please verify that your server is ready to take request.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code it is hard to pinpoint what you're doing wrong, but it looks like you're passing in the string

```
"tcp://port&IP"
```

instead of something like

```
"tcp://" + IP + ":" + port
```